# iPhone lighttpd: where is the localhost folder

Tags: php, iphone, host, lighttpd

I have installed phppod and lighthttpd toggle successfully on my iPhone, and I got the index page including iphpPod + phpinfo.php + sample.html when entering localhost on safari.

All I want is to find the localhost folder so I could upload my files to, I'm accessing my iPhone files with iPhone Explorer.

Anybody know where I could find the localhost folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location in this file `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` (it contains the configuration for the webserver), the line looks something like:

`server.document-root = "/var/www/"`

depending on your server configuration.

Comment: I'm very beginner in this, could you explain how could I see the files inside the localhost folder, using iphone explorer I can't see any of those files you have mentioned only root and apps and it doen't have these folders. how could I reach my localhost files ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanOsama I don't know about Phone Explorer but you can ssh into your iPhone using a program like WinSCP, Filezila or any SSH client. The default username/password are `root/alpine`, you must have OpenSSH installed on your iPhone.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm in using SSH and I see two folders Media & Library, where could I find the localhost folder ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanOsama [here's](http://i.imgur.com/eTVgk.png) a quick guide, the rest is in my answer.

Comment: I get what you said and I tried it at the mac terminal, many thanks. but I still can't put my files in this folders I just can view them. I don't know the terminal codes. Is there any visiual software I can use, I have mac fetch and I can see the Media and Library folders. but how to see the rest of the folders ??? Thanks